# Handling exception in setup stage of python context manager

Tags: python, contextmanager

I am looking for some clarification on how to handle exceptions in the setup stage of a context-manager, in the case (for example) that a file I'm trying to access doesn't exist.

Some background: I am subclassing a class `Maps` from another library which provides access to some data on-disk. `Maps` constructs the appropriate file name to access, based on some information that I pass at instantiation. It is not completely straightforward to predict the filename that `Maps` tries to load.

`Maps` does not close the underlying file object, so I am trying to fix that in my subclass by providing `__enter__` and `__exit__`.

```
class BetterMaps(Maps):
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.data.close()
```

So, we can do something like:

```
with BetterMaps(name, releaseversion) as bettermaps:
    do_work_here(bettermaps)
```

and the file object is indeed closed. *However*, this only works when the underlying file actually exists: if the file does not exist, then `AssertionError` or `NoMapsHereError` is raised, depending on the exact circumstances. In the paradigm I was using before, I instantiated `Maps` something like:

```
try:
    maps = Maps(name, releaseversion)
except (AssertionError, NoMapsHereError) as e:
    proceed = False
else:
    proceed = True

if proceed:
    do_work_here(maps)
```

which handled the exceptions in the case that there was no data to read.

Now, I'm not sure how to embed this behavior in the context-manager syntax I'm using. One attempt I made so far was to modify `__enter__` to log whether the data existed, and return `False` if not:

```
class BetterMaps(Maps):
    def __enter__(self):
        try:
            self.data_dne = False
            return self
        except (NoMapsHereError, AssertionError):
            self.data_dne = True
            return False
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        if self.data_dne:
            pass
        else:
            self.data.close()

with BetterMaps(name, releaseversion) as bettermaps:
    if not bettermaps:
        pass
    else:
        do_work_here(bettermaps)
```

with the intent that in the case that setup failed (data couldn't be loaded), `bettermaps` would take on the value `False`, which would bypass `do_work_here()`. This does not work, and `AssertionError` is still raised. Are errors raised within `__init__` not subject to the logic in `__enter__`?

More broadly, is there a preferred way to handle cases where something in `__init__` breaks? I recognize that in my case I could attempt to reconstruct the filename that's being accessed, and stop if the file doesn't exist; but I would **strongly** prefer not to do that, since it would complicate my codebase. Feedback is appreciated.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. You can either wrap the whole `with` block in a `try...except` or just the constructor. Trying to suppress an exception in your `__enter__` method looks like a bad idea.

Comment: I also thought about wrapping the `with` block in `try...except`, but it seemed clumsy, which made me think there should be a way to do both at once.